# How does .NET Core on Linux determine what port a SQL Server instance listens on?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web API which runs in a Docker container on Ubuntu and connects out to a SQL Server database (SQL Server 2012 SP3) on a Windows server.  This works in 3 out of 4 of out environments, but in one environment it cannot connect to the SQL Server and I am trying to troubleshoot it.

The error is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

The SQL Server has an instance name: SQLSERVER1\APPS.  From the Linux server I can ping the server SQLSERVER1 and telnet to SQLSERVER1 1372 (1372 is the port for the APPS instance: so network connectivity is there.

The only space I can see for the problem to occur is how .NET Core translates the instance name to a port number.  Does anyone know how this is done and whether it is configurable on the client machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remote named instance listening port discovery relies [SQL Server Browser Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx) and protocol. <strike>As you cannot leverage this for your Linux docker image,</strike> I suggest you connect by explicitly specifying the port and omitting the instance name: [`"server=tcp:SQLSERVER1,1372;database=...;..."`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The name or network address of the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. The port number can be specified after the server name: `server=tcp:servername, portnumber`

BTW if you live the instance name it should make no difference whatsoever after you explicitly specify the port.

PS. After reading again the question, the issue is related but different cause. Normally the Linux container *can* discover the Windows SQL Server, as the Browser service is probably up and running (proof that 3 envs. it works). In the 4th environment it means something blocks the discovery. Either the Browser service is stopped, or the browser discovery protocol listening port is blocked in the FW (UDP 1433), or perhaps the UDP packet (or the response!) is lost somewhere between the container and the server. You can investigate and find the root cause, *but*, you can also just ignore the problem and work around the issue by... specifying the port explicitly, just as I showed.

Comment: Thanks, this helped with my debugging.  The `tcp:` prefix works but does not appear to be required...  but I still can't connect from the Docker container even when specifying the port.  A test console app connects using the same connection string from outside Docker, so it's obviously a Docker config issue.  Somewhat stumped now.